# Http header Content-Length in camel cxf client request

Tags: java, web-services, http-headers, apache-camel, cxf

We have a simple camel route "from->to":

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:testServiceProvider?loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
<to uri="cxf:bean:testServiceClient?loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
```

This route acts like a router or proxy for a third party's web service:

- Clients use it as endpoint.
- Adds WSS headers to Soap message.
- Route requests to real endpoint.

Service and client in this proxy are created with `cxf` beans.

The endpoint's web service seems to require `Content-Length` HTTP header, but `cxf` requests to endpoint does not contain this header by default. All the requests done by this proxy receive the same response:

```
HTTP response '411: Length required' when communicating with https://host:port/testService
```

We tried to add this header with an OutInterceptor, adding it to PROTOCOL_HEADERS:

```
Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
headers.put("Content-Length", Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(messageLength)));
```

Two questions:

How to know the value of `messageLength`?
Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with http:conduit, disabling AllowChunking. This will force cxf to include Content-Length header in the request. By default cxf behaviour is to allow chunking, so it can be generating the problem you're facing, even specifying the Content-length header.

```
<http:conduit name="{http://namespace}WebService.http-conduit">
    <http:client AllowChunking="false" CacheControl="No-Cache" 
ContentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" ConnectionTimeout="900000" 
ReceiveTimeout="900000" Connection="Keep-Alive" />
</http:conduit>
```

Comment: http:conduit is not working for me I am giving name as "*.http-conduit" .Please help me on proper way of applying it,

Comment: tried below request header did not sent content-type                                                
final ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client); config.getHttpConduit().getClient().setAllowChunking(false);

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the CXF documentation you may be able to use the relayHeaders functionality to propogate headers from the "from" endpoint to the "to" endpoint.

[CXF Bean Docs](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

Alternatively you could copy the value of the content-length from the inbound message as suggested here...

*"If you want to keep those headers in the old version of camel, you need 
to put the headers into a map and put this map into message header with 
the key "org.apache.cxf.message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS"."*

[Copy headers](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-CXF-Drops-Headers-td5590792.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PillHead, but the proxy adds Web Service Security headers to the soap message, so the Content-Length is not the same. I'll edit my question.